# VB.NET Web Application Project cannot add merge with C#.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am trying to merge my vb.net Web application project with my c# mvc project not ideal at all but the project is too big to do it any other way.

any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Ash :D

Comment: It's quite difficult to figure out what question you are asking here - help converting vb.net to c#?  Merging template files?  Send me the codes? More specifics on what you need help with and what you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: hi sorry for the confusion.

basically I have 2 projects 
    a vb.net web application
    a C#.net MVC project

I am trying to mearge the two projects into one project... not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: It is not possible to do what you want without converting them to the same language first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio (or any other IDE I'm aware of that can target .net), you can not mix multiple languages in the same project.  For an asp.net project that does on-demand compilation, you can not mix multiple languages in most cases.

If you want to edit via text editor or work around this, you can compile to .netmodules (using compiler switches - for csc.exe, it's /t:module), [then link them together](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe.aspx). This is a bit cumbersome, so most people do not do it.

Otherwise, you can convert one language into another - for example, convert the vb.net to c# - and manually put the types into one project.  There are a few language converters out there, but all of them that I've tried have a few faults with complex constructs.  I've had good luck loading a project into [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/), and using it's built-in conversion tool to get me 95% of the way there.

Comment: Cheers Philip this was great advice!